# Does limiting the maximum number of concurrent connections also limit the number of concurrent requests?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

[This Web tutorial](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) and also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682147/aiohttp-rate-limiting-parallel-requests/48682456#48682456) recommend the use of semaphores to limit the number of concurrent requests made with aiohttp.

I am confused because `aiohttp` provides on its own a facility to limit the number of concurrent connections (`limit` and `limit_per_host`, [documented here](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#connectors)) - so is using semaphores not reinventing the wheel?

Perhaps it's not. Can there be multiple concurrent requests per connection? It appears there can, as per [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) and also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812022/number-of-http-requests-per-tcp-connection). So perhaps setting `limit` and/or `limit_per_host` in `aiohttp`, which as per the docs I linked to limits concurrent *connections*, does not have the effect of limiting concurrent *requests*.

I'm still confused because if this is the case, what's the use of these parameters `aiohttp` provides? Why would a user want to limit *connections* rather than *requests*? But such reasoning of course doesn't entail anything so I was ready to move on and use semaphores.

Then I stumbled upon [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196974/aiohttp-set-maximum-number-of-requests-per-second). It has two relatively highly upvoted answers. One of these answers again recommends using semaphores. But the other answer recommends making use of the `aiohttp` facilities `limit` and `limit_per_host`. If this answer is correct then limiting *connections* in `aiohttp` also limits *requests* - so no semaphores are necessary <sub>(unless one also wishes to limit the rate of requests per second, which is not what I'm tackling here)</sub>

And this is what I'd like to ask in this question. Does limiting concurrent *connections* in `aiohttp` via `limit` and/or `limit_per_host` also limit concurrent *requests*? I suppose that the answer depends on whether `aiohttp` does or does not use only one connection per request, which I don't know either.

Does `aiohttp` only use one connection per request? Does limiting concurrent connections also limit concurrent requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does aiohttp only use one connection per request?

By default if you make several requests to single host using same `ClientSession` instance, aiohttp can reuse existing connection(s): `By default all connectors support keep-alive connections` ([source](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#connectors))

You can share connection between different sessions using `connector_owner=False` ([source](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.1/client_advanced.html#connectors)).

But making single request is possible only through single connection if that's what you're asking about.

---

> Does limiting concurrent connections also limit concurrent requests?

It does (for example, see plot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55259755/1113207)), but you shouldn't rely on it anyway.

"Connection limit" is a low-level detail of `aiohttp`'s request implementation. You don't really want to work with low-level detail, what you  want is to work with high-level abstraction "limit number of concurrent requests". And that's what semaphore can be used for.

To better understand the idea consider following situation: your script makes concurrent requests using `aiohttp` and some another http client library same time. Relying on `aiohttp`'s `limit` won't affect other library. Global semaphore on the other hand will allow to limit all requests regardless of how they are implemented.

Comment: A minor question: *"Connection limit" is a low-level detail of aiohttp's request implementation.* – in this case why is it exposed to the end user?

Comment: @gaazkam I don't know if `aiohttp`'s developer(s) will agree, but I think it shouldn't have. On the other hand `aiohttp` itself is rather low-level library in context of making simple requests. Anyway, I see only advantages in using semaphore over `limit`.

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia article refers to persistent connections, i.e. re-using the same TCP connection for multiple requests, the requests still being serial rather than concurrent. HTTP/2 does allow multiplexing *concurrent* requests on a single TCP connection, but aiohttp doesn't implement it.

That makes the two limits equivalent: limiting the number of parallel connections effectively limits the number of concurrent requests. As Mikhail points out, this can be considered an implementation detail.